# SearchBar not filtering Firebase data

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I have a view controller with a searchBar and 2 tableViews. The top tableView(chargesTableView) loads info from Firebase and the bottom tableView (patChargesTableView) has a listener attached. The issue I'm having is with the searchBar, before implementing the searchBar, Firebase DB was loading and displaying properly. Now, with the searchBar, when Firebase loads, all rows are displaying the same info I have in row 0 and the search option does not work. It is weird and I'm not sure what else to do. Any ideas/suggestions on how to tackle this issue are greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
   var chargesClassFromCell = [Charges]() 
    var searchBar = UISearchBar()
    var filteredCharges = [Charges]()
    var inSearchMode = false

 // MARK: - SearchBar
    
    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    }
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        let searchText = searchText.lowercased()
        if searchText.isEmpty || searchText == " " {
            inSearchMode = false
            chargesTableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            inSearchMode = true
            filteredCharges = chargesClassFromCell.filter({ (chargeDescrip) -> Bool in
                return chargeDescrip.chargeDescription.contains(searchText)
            })
            chargesTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.endEditing(true)
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
        searchBar.text = nil
        inSearchMode = false
    }
    

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView == chargesTableView {
            if inSearchMode {
                return filteredCharges.count
            } else {
                return chargesClassFromCell.count
            }
        }else {
            if tableView == patChargesTableView {
            }
        }
        return patChargesClassFromCell.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if tableView == chargesTableView {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChargesCell", for: indexPath) as? ChargesCell
            var charges: Charges!
            if inSearchMode {
                charges = filteredCharges[indexPath.row]
            } else {
                charges = chargesClassFromCell[indexPath.row]
            }
            cell!.charges = charges
            
            return cell!
            
        } else if tableView == patChargesTableView {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PatChargesCell", for: indexPath) as? PatChargesCell
            cell!.configurePatChargesListCell(patCharges: patChargesClassFromCell[indexPath.row])
            cell!.patChargesCount.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)" + " - "
            return cell!
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any calls to the Firebase API in your code. If the problem is reproducible without Firebase, that's great but means I'd remove that tag. If it is only reproducible *with* Firebase, please make sure the relevant code is in the question. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: tag has been removed.

Comment: @Eddie I think your logic for checking if it should display filtered information vs not filtered information is a bit confusing. I would avoid relying on "inSearchMode" and instead maybe rely on checking the if the filteredArray has data (filteredArray.count > 0)....Furthermore, I would use a breakpoint to check the contents of filteredCharges in your cellForRowAt delegate method.